# Editor for blog writing

Tags: blog, wysiwyg, text-editor

I have created a blog site in ASP.NET and I am using dynamic syntax highlighter. I need a editor in which I can write my blog and necessary code should wrap inside the

```
<pre>
```

syntax. Which editor should I use for this in which I can easily convert my text to HTML format to save in database

Comment: follow this:https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-Insert-and-Retrieve-Display-TinyMCE-contents-from-database-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your needs. Do you need to include media - if yes which ones, do you need additinal plugins…
Here is a quick comparison of some JavaScript WYSIWYG-editors: http://blog.eike.se/2009/04/comparison-of-major-open-source.html